# PHP / Laravel - Advanced relationship and dynamic amount of columns

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I am trying to recreate below logic in Laravel:

[image]

Now this is a dynamic sailing schedule, currently created in Excel. In my Laravel app, I would like to for each origin/destination (Origin to Destination):

- Define as many "routes" dynamically (For example, one route is the Atlantic Sky on the 30th of October, on the Carrier ACL)
- Define as many ETD and ETA columns (cityname and date) to my route. For example, I may want to specify that a specific route has two ETD points

  - This could for example be: New York 6/NOV **and** Boston 12/NOV
  - Same goes for ETA columns. I need to dynamically be able to add more columns, should the specific route require this

I am having a hard time grasping the logic required to do this.

Right now, my thoughts were to:

1. Create a `Carriers` model and table, which holds all the different carriers (for example "ACL")
2. Create a `Vessels` model and table, which holds all the different vessels, for a specific carrier (For example "Atlantic Sky" and "Atlantic Sail"). I will then define a `hasOne` relationship on these two models.

Now I will also need some sort of table, that holds the specific route (For example **New York** to **Copenhagen** and then list all carriers that have this route.

However, I am not able to grasp how I should do this when I need to be able to dynamically add as many `ETD` and `ETA` points?

My thought was to:

3. Create a `Routes` model, which then holds the routing information such as (vessel_id, cut_off_date) - but how do I go about creating the `etd1, etd2, etd3, eta1, eta2, eta3 columns when this can vary from route to route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your `Route` model would have a vessel-id and the start and end destinations. Then a `routes_stops` model or something like that would detail all of the individual stops between the start & end.

Comment: Would it make sense to store the "stops" in `json` in the `routes` table? and then dynamically get them as an array?

Comment: I would start with breaking them out into a separate table. This way you can fully leverage the database relationships. By stuffing that info in a JSONB blob it will be harder to query, filter on, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you pass the data as JSON data in the body of a POST request.

Otherwise, pass them as a url-encoded json object in the url parameters.

Something like this:

```
$myDataObj = [["type" => "ETD", "city" = "New York", "date" = "6/NOV"]
              ["type" => "ETA", "city" = "Boston", "date" = "12/NOV"]];

$myDataJSON = json_encode($myDataObj);
```

Then you can add `$myDataJSON` as a parameter value in your json-encoded url.